# Join two fields MongoDB for report

Tags: mongodb

I have following collections:

```
> db.website.find()
{ "_id" : 1, "domainName" : "test1.com", "hosting" : "hostgator.com" }
{ "_id" : 2, "domainName" : "test2.com", "hosting" : "aws.amazon.com" }
{ "_id" : 3, "domainName" : "test3.com", "hosting" : "aws.amazon.com" }
{ "_id" : 4, "domainName" : "test4.com", "hosting" : "hostgator.com" }
{ "_id" : 5, "domainName" : "test5.com", "hosting" : "aws.amazon.com" }
{ "_id" : 6, "domainName" : "test6.com", "hosting" : "cloud.google.com" }
{ "_id" : 7, "domainName" : "test7.com", "hosting" : "aws.amazon.com" }
{ "_id" : 8, "domainName" : "test8.com", "hosting" : "hostgator.com" }
{ "_id" : 9, "domainName" : "test9.com", "hosting" : "cloud.google.com" }
{ "_id" : 10, "domainName" : "test10.com", "hosting" : "godaddy.com" }
```

and this one:

```
 db.websitegroup.find()
{ "_id" : "aws.amazon.com", "total" : 4, "hosting" : "aws.amazon.com" }
{ "_id" : "hostgator.com", "total" : 3, "hosting" : "hostgator.com" }
{ "_id" : "cloud.google.com", "total" : 2, "hosting" : "cloud.google.com" }
{ "_id" : "godaddy.com", "total" : 1, "hosting" : "godaddy.com" }
```

I want an .csv report with all the fields of website collection + total field of websitegroup, so I did the following in mongo console:

```
var joinTable = db.website.aggregate([{$lookup:{from:"websitegroup",localField:"hosting",foreignField:"hosting",as:"datosadjuntos"}}]);
db.createCollection("joinTable");
db.joinTable.insert(joinTable.toArray());
```

and in normal console I used mongoexport as it follows:

```
mongoexport --db test --collection joinTable --type=csv --out /home/joinTable_`date +"%d-%m-%y-%H:%M:%S"`.csv --fields _id,domainName,hosting,datosadjuntos.total
```

I get all the fields except for the datosadjuntos.total

[image]

if I export it again but replacing datosadjuntos.total for just datosadjuntos.total like this:

```
mongoexport --db test --collection joinTable --type=csv --out /home/lavenec1/reportes_soyplus/joinTable_`date +"%d-%m-%y-%H:%M:%S"`.csv --fields _id,domainName,hosting,datosadjuntos
```

then I get this:

[image]

it seems there's a [] surrounding each record...

How to get this report with datosadjuntos.total correctly??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't possible to export only a sub-field of "datosadjuntos". Per the [mongoexport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/) documentation:

> For JSON output formats, mongoexport includes only the specified field(s) and the _id field, and if the specified field(s) is a field within a sub-document, the mongoexport includes the sub-document with all its fields, not just the specified field within the document.

Try modifying the aggregation to return the data in a way that will be accessible to mongoexport.

The [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#perform-a-join-with-lookup) returns results in an array field, as there may be multiple values returned for each lookup value. You'll want to add an [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) stage to the end of your aggregation pipeline to allow each result document to be accessed directly and [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) the results to a field that can be accessed by the export.

For example:

```
db.website.aggregate([
  {$lookup:{from:"websitegroup",localField:"hosting",foreignField:"hosting",as:"datosadjuntos"}},
  { "$unwind" : { "path" : "$datosadjuntos"}},
  { "$project" : { "_id" : 1, "domainName" : 1, "hosting" : 1, "datos_total" : "$datosadjuntos.total" } }
]);
```

The results would then be the following:

```
{ "_id" : 2, "domainName" : "test2.com", "hosting" : "aws.amazon.com", "datos_total" : 4 }
{ "_id" : 3, "domainName" : "test3.com", "hosting" : "aws.amazon.com", "datos_total" : 4 }
{ "_id" : 4, "domainName" : "test4.com", "hosting" : "hostgator.com", "datos_total" : 3 }
{ "_id" : 5, "domainName" : "test5.com", "hosting" : "aws.amazon.com", "datos_total" : 4 }
{ "_id" : 6, "domainName" : "test6.com", "hosting" : "cloud.google.com", "datos_total" : 2 }
{ "_id" : 7, "domainName" : "test7.com", "hosting" : "aws.amazon.com", "datos_total" : 4 }
{ "_id" : 8, "domainName" : "test8.com", "hosting" : "hostgator.com", "datos_total" : 3 }
{ "_id" : 9, "domainName" : "test9.com", "hosting" : "cloud.google.com", "datos_total" : 2 }
{ "_id" : 10, "domainName" : "test10.com", "hosting" : "godaddy.com", "datos_total" : 1 }
```